# Number of distinct regions formed in a plane by thirteen lines and one circle

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, solution-verification, contest-math

> Thirteen straight lines are drawn in a plane such that no two lines
> are parallel to each other and no three lines are concurrent. A circle
> is drawn in the same plane such that all the points of intersection of
> the above lines lie inside the circle. How many distinct regions are
> formed in the plane?

Total number of regions that will be formed in this case will be $$1 + \sum\limits_{i=1}^n n$$ where $n$ equals to the total number of lines. So when I put $n=13$ in the above equation, I get total number of regions as $92$ and I thought this will be the answer but I was wrong. The correct answer provided is $118$. What have I done wrong? Or is the answer provided wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have not yet accounted for the circle. Without the circle, you are correct that the number of regions is $92$, but drawing the circle creates more regions.

Comment: @MikeEarnest : Now I get it. So we have to count the number of finite regions inside the circle which will be $92$ and then we have to count the number of infinite regions outside the circle and then sum up them together ,right?

Comment: That is indeed the idea.

Comment: Indeed $92 + 2\cdot 13 = 118$.